# Embed ttf font within PDF when cmap table is missing

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, truetype

**Problem**

I'm building up a PDF from scratch using TCPDF. However, when I try and embed a ttf font that does not have a cmap table defined within it, TCPDF throws an error. I've also tried using other PDF building libraries (*foliojs/pdfkit, Setasign/FPDF*) but they throw similar errors due to the missing cmap table.

**Background / Context**

In short, I'm building a PDF editor engine. Currently, the engine can accept an existing PDF and extract all the necessary assets (*images, fonts, text, etc.*) required to re-build the PDF. One of those assets being the fonts from the original PDF.

I'm using the ["extract" CLI command from MuPDF](https://www.mupdf.com/docs/manual-mutool-extract.html) to extract the fonts from the original PDF. This is working well and the extracted fonts appear to be correct. I have verified this by opening up the extracted fonts in FontForge and can confirm that the correct set/subset of characters is present.

**Things I have Tried**

I'm using a number of different tools to gather additional data about each extracted ttf file.

- The library *phenx/php-font-lib* helps with getting generic font data such as the font name, postscript name as well as the unicode character map. However it fails when trying to get the unicode character map for fonts with a missing cmap header.
- [TTX](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ttx) helps with dumping the tables in the ttf file. This tool also confirms the presence/absence of the cmap table.
- I've tried using font converters to export/rebuild the ttf files hoping the cmap table would then be present.
- As mentioned earlier, I've tried using other PDF building libraries to render the text with its corresponding font family but they throw errors due to the missing cmap table as well.

**Questions**

- Is there a way to programmatically repair or add the missing cmap table back into a ttf file?
- Is it even necessary to add the missing cmap table back into the ttf file when PDF readers have no problem interpreting the embedded font in the original PDF?
- Should I be passing in a specific set of arguments to `TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont()` to accommodate ttf files with a missing cmap?

Comment: Re `the correct set/subset of characters is present`, if the font doesn't have a cmap table, then it doesn't have any _characters_ since it is the cmap table that determines characters (as opposed to glyphs).

Comment: @PeterConstable Okay, so how would one go about using a font with no cmap table / no characters but does have glyphs?

Comment: IIUC, a PDF document can represent text on a page by referencing glyph IDs rather than characters.